# Why generate_password_hash() creates a different hash for the same password?

Tags: python, werkzeug, sha512

```
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash

password_hash = generate_password_hash(password='qwerty', method='sha512')

print(password_hash)
```

I get a different hash every time I run it on pycharm. Here are some results:

sha512$C6Q28TMjmhzqiJ9I$4d59ead48cde4dc1b0dcc359e5479cede957cb49013602bd2028f3f3eeba55386e441d70866feb70e2eeb7ab1108aad9980241fb87275282a7181f22da329b44

sha512$Y48EzPVVB3OgFvTp$294f00b6129e870480661090b5f946f601020c601c90bb12ecb17c8b8fa9b214cf8afd4954f5d3c50b65f14aa21caf9e0f41aaa718f1a5d22d18da49a70b1f12

sha512$RN4rNnGhSV95T806$1dfa460209d297e682e610c4f33178125719cc3f6c670f4110b5be405e63ad312a09e0dff8800f3fc23afaff2d892f73e433d53be447a268aacaede2f8d2a461

Shouldn't it be this and be the same all the time?:
sha512$0dd3e512642c97ca3f747f9a76e374fbda73f9292823c0313be9d78add7cdd8f72235af0c553dd26797e78e1854edee0ae002f8aba074b066dfce1af114e32f8

Comment: A hash is supposed to be different since its supposed to be (in difference to encryption) an one way process. The hashes you are generating can be verified using `werkzeug.security.check_password_hash(<hash>,<password>) which returns bool.`

Comment: Do NOT use SHA512 as a password-hashing function. It is NOT suitable for this usage.

Answer (score 3):

Good quality password hashing makes use of a [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)):

> In cryptography, a salt is random data that is used as an additional input to a one-way function that hashes data, a password or passphrase. Salts are used to safeguard passwords in storage. Historically, only a cryptographic hash function of the password was stored on a system, but over time, additional safeguards were developed to protect against duplicate or common passwords being identifiable (as their hashes are identical). Salting is one such protection.
>
> A new salt is randomly generated for each password. Typically, the salt and the password (or its version after key stretching) are concatenated and fed to a cryptographic hash function, and the output hash value (but not the original password) is stored with the salt in a database. Hashing allows later authentication without keeping and therefore risking exposure of the plaintext password if the authentication data store is compromised. Note that due to this, salts don't need to be encrypted or stored separately from the hashed password itself, because even if an attacker has access to the database with the hash values and the salts, the correct use of said salts will hinder common attacks.

Comment: it doesn't matter if I salt the password or not. Every time I run the code (with or without salting) a different hash is generated instead of the same one.

Comment: How are you doing it without salt? The method always applies a salt and throws an error if you use a salt length <= 0. The only way to avoid that is to use `method='plain'`, in which case you shouldn't have a hash?

Comment: @PaulGed — From the documentation of the method you are calling "This method can not generate unsalted passwords".

Comment: I tried to simplify this code to make it so that it can be answered quickly. If I edit the code to :
password_hash = generate_password_hash(password='qwerty', method='sha512', salt_length=10)
it still generates a different hash to the same password every time I run PyCharm. Also the method='plain' is just repeating a default *arg already so there's no reason to place it in

Comment: @PaulGed — `salt_length=10` doesn't make it not include a salt. `method='plain'` doesn't repeat a default argument, the default is `method='pbkdf2:sha256'` and you're overriding it with `method='sha512'`

Comment: ok instead of method='sha512' I put in method='pbkdf2:sha256'

again same problem, a different hash is generated every time for 'qwerty' on pycharm. Here are a few run results:

pbkdf2:sha256:260000$iJIDBxEvxCySOVFH$a3b99a0576268ae82d2721ce0d303828121b47cf7be0d175063b9843a43fb56a

pbkdf2:sha256:260000$cKUyDkxJzDQHmUlB$d4106f02d25391479a60293291f108301d3f5a30aa9204cc41fcb8af39db6969

Comment: Well, yes, the default isn't `method='plain'`! And generating a unique hash each time is **not** a problem. It's a **good** thing.

Comment: no it is a problem. I want the same hash for the same password, how can you check the hash of a password typed in if it's a new one generated all the time in a server? there's no way to cross check it.

Comment: also your method='plain' just shows the password:

plain$$qwerty

method='plain' isn't method='pbkdf2:sha256'

Comment: Umm. You use `werkzeug.security.check_password_hash` which uses the salt from the hash. As I said, salts are a good thing. They aren't something which makes password hashing completely worthless.

Comment: that's the thing though, it doesn't work in my code. I pull the hash from the SQL, run the werkzeug.security.check_password_hash and it comes back false. I do it in a sandbox .py file and same thing. I thought it's because the hash isn't the same, so now I have no clue. I'll keep checking. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: As per the docs https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/utils/#module-werkzeug.security you can change the salt length but that method cannot generate an unsalted hash

Answer (score 0):

this was supposed to be a sandbox example of a hash that was pulled from a SQL table, there were a few things I did wrong:

1. for check_password_hash I accidentally was checking 2 hashes in pwhash and password
2. SQL password change wasn't committed to the database so it didn't check the most up-to-date password